# Repeated question bug?

Tags: support, bug

I just posted a question, when I was posting something happened and the site shown an error without any description. I clicked “send” again, the same error appeared. I refreshed the page, tried to post again, an error appeared again, when clicking again, the site informed me the question was already posted.

I didn't click too fast between each trial. I clicked first and went to do some chore, than clicked again and went to do another one, etc.

> [image]

Comment: Apparently, the error notice notwithstanding, submitting the question worked.

Comment: I've merged the three questions and deleted the two merge stubs, so in that repsect order is restored.

Comment: It happened with me when I had slow network. But, the site stopped me saying that there is an exact duplicate already posted.

Comment: @BillyRubina I had a similar problem on Meta SE recently as I explained in [Period of a few minutes where I was getting error messages with posting and updating a question on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355618). It seems to be related to some SE occasional search related problems, including when you had your problem, e.g., as asked in [Search is extremely slow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356685). Fortunately, an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356706) there shows SE is aware, believes knows the issue, has put in a temporary fix & is working on a permanent fix.